# Adding value from a field to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, parameters, getelementbyid

I have a javascript function `checkStatus()` which accepts four arguments`bus_company_name,bus_id,bus_time` and `bus_date` . The first three arguments are coming from database, but the fourth one will be entered by user . For that I have written the HTML like :

```
{foreach name = feach item = k from = $allBuses}
        <p>
        {$k->bus_company_name}<br />
        A/C {$k->bus_is_ac}<br />
        Date : <input type="text" name="date" id="dt" />yyyy/mm/dd

        <a href="javascript:checkStatus('{$k->bus_company_name}','{$k->bus_id}','{$k->bus_time}',jrny_date)">Status</a>
        </p>
  {/foreach}
```

I want `jrny_date` from input type with id `date` . How can I implement that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use this, you will pass the element value as param.

```
javascript:checkStatus('{$k->bus_company_name}','{$k->bus_id}','{$k->bus_time}',document.getElementById('dt').value)
```

But you also can get inside the function checkStatus.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looping through a list of items, I would recommend using the current index at each iteration to create a unique date ID.  You can then pass this to your script and get the element's value by ID there:

```
{foreach name = feach key = i item = k from = $allBuses}
        {$k->bus_company_name}<br />
        A/C {$k->bus_is_ac}<br />
        Date : <input type="text" name="date" id="dt_{$i}" />yyyy/mm/dd

        <a href="javascript:checkStatus('{$k->bus_company_name}','{$k->bus_id}','{$k->bus_time}','dt_{$i}')">Status</a>
{/foreach}

<script>
    function checkStatus(name, id, time, date_id){
        var date = document.getElementById(date_id);
        if(date){
            alert(date.value);
            // Do something fancy with the date
        } 
    }
</script>
```